# Getting user's display name from WindowsIdentity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm in a ASP.NET application using Windows Authentication.

I'm using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the username of the currently authenticated user, which gets me a username in the format DOMAIN\USERNAME.  This is working fine.

Is there an easy way to convert this to a display name (e.g. "Richard Gadsden") like the one that appears on the top of my start menu in XP?

If I have to, I guess I can go through System.DirectoryServices and query into ADSI, but surely there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on just how to do that:

http://www.youcanlearnseries.com/Programming%20Tips/CSharp/LDAPReader.aspx

Comment: that article you linked to is 3 pages long and I'm not sure which code to use. Can you post the code needed specifically in your answer plz ?

Answer (score 15):

There is an easier way now, use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

...

   Dim CurrentUser As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current
   Dim DisplayName As String = CurrentUser.DisplayName
```

Comment: This helps only if you can get UserPrincipal out of the WindowsIdentity object. The question relies on working on a WindowsIdentity object - and extracting the user name out of it. I can see how one can get a WindowsPrincipal from a WindowsIdentity object, but cannot find how to get a UserPrincipal.

Comment: I figured out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808955/can-i-get-active-directory-attributes-from-the-windowsprincipal/2809817#2809817) that you can get a UserPrincipal simply based on a domain. So your answer does help (my downvote is now locked, however... Please edit your answer with any minor change so I will be allowed to remove my downvote (SO's policies..).

Comment: The problems with this answer are:
* It assumes you're trying to do it with the currently authenticated user, which seems to be true in the asker's case but isn't necessarily true generally.
* for some users, UserPrincipal.Current doesn't work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491333/userprincipal-current-throws-invalidcastexception) - this is the problem I'm trying to work around by getting it from WindowsIdentity.

Answer (score 1):

I guess ADSI is the way to go. It's pretty easy. I don't see an easier way. You just query for `LDAP://<SID=user-sid>` and get the distinguished name property.