# Can I get Active Directory attributes from the WindowsPrincipal?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I would like to get the Employee-ID for the currently logged in user. Is that easily available in some .Net class or do I need to do some sort of LDAP query?

Any tips welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even easier - use the new .NET 3.5 `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` features.

See the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) for details.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain. "YOURDOMAIN");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, loginName);

if(user != null)
{
   string empID = user.EmployeeId;
}
```

The new strongly typed principal classes make it a breeze to work with AD.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. Note it is UserPrincipal.EmployeeId
not ...ID
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Marc, I was searching how to get a User Principal out of a Windows Identity. Here I realized that if I have the domain I can do that, with nothing to do to my Windows Identity object.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score -1):

Used AD query - very simple:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeID");
ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", loginName);

result = ds.FindOne();
if (result != null)
{
    personnelNumber = result.Properties["employeeID"][0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where does result come from? "result = ds.FindOne();"