# UserPrincipal.Current throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to get display name for the logged in user name using

```
UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

This is working fine in IIS Express but throwing InvalidCastException in IIS 8.5.

I found that there is an issue reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748790/userprincipal-current-throws-invalidcastexception) but unfortunately MS not able to reproduce. Any suggestions or alternatives?

I am using ASP.Net MVC with Windows Authentication.

Comment: What are you trying to obtain? just the logged in user name? which version on MVC are you using?

Comment: Logggd in user full name. I am using MVC 5.